# vue-router not working when accessed url directly in a browser - 404 error

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I set up my `vue-router` in history mode to get rid of `#`. After doing this change, my application throws 404 error every time I access my app's url in browser (e.g. http://myapp/verify_account). However it works when accessing the same url form landing page (when vue-router is already loaded).

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Home from '@/views/Home.vue'
import Verify from '@/views/Verify.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

export default new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      name: 'Home',
      path: '/',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      name: 'Verify',
      path: '/verify_account',
      component: Verify
    }
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I had to add some directives to my `nginx` configuration to resolve my routes correctly. Basically, I added `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;` directive to my `nginx.conf` file after reading [HTML5 History Mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html) section in vue-router documentation.

**my_app.nginx.conf**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  server_name _;

  charset utf-8;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  index index.html index.htm;

  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

Depended if your application is served by nginx, apache or node.js check [this examples](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations) for inspiration.